# Scrapy over-writes results when requests are run concurrently?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have been running a Scrapy scraper, and noticed that it is returning duplicate results. In other words, it is assigning results for an item from another item.

My settings file has `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 100` and does not set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`.

This is my spider code:

```
def start_requests(self):
    settings = get_project_settings()
    ids = settings.get('IDS', None)
    for i, id in enumerate(ids):
        yield FormRequest(
            url=self._FORM_URL,
            formdata={ 'id': id },
            meta={'id': id},
        )

def parse(self, response):
    addr_xpath = '//div[@class="w80p  left floatRight"]//text()'
    addresses = response.xpath(addr_xpath).extract()
    if not addresses:
        raise DropItem("Can't find address")

    item = MyItem()
    item['address'] = ', '.join(addresses)
    return item
```

This is my item code:

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    id = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
```

Some of my items have different IDs but the same address, even though the web page I'm scraping returns different addresses for the different IDs. I think results are being returned in parallel and accidentally over-writing each other.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Scrapy v0.24.6 and Twisted v16.6.0.

Comment: Why are you using scrapy v0.24.6? That's like 5 years old by now. The [latest version on pypi is 1.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Scrapy/1.3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably happening because cookie sessions. To use multiple cookie session in one spider you need to use `cookiejar` meta parameter in your request:

```
for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'cookiejar': i},
                         callback=self.parse_page)
```

As per [Multiple cookie sessions per spider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider):

> There is support for keeping multiple cookie sessions per spider by using the cookiejar Request meta key. By default it uses a single cookie jar (session), but you can pass an identifier to use different ones.